# extending wired network through wireless connected computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, tv, bridge

I have a windows 7 system connected to my home network through wireless.
The system has an unused wired NIC.

I have installed a smart TV next to the system. I would like to connect the TV to my home network through the windows 7 system and its wired port.

What do I have to configure (and how) so that the TV will gain access to the network (either using DHCP or manually)?

Comment: You are aware that such a configuration will require the PC (acting as a wireless access point) to be operational in order to provide the connection for the TV, right?  I.E. you want to use a 50 watt (or more?) computer system to do the job of a 10 watt box.

Comment: @sawdust - Its an HTPC system. It is always on anyway. Your comment is completely irrelevant. Are you the green police?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure Windows to bridge the wired NIC and the Wireless device.

You can do this by selecting the two adapters in the  Control "Network Connections" window and choose to "Bridge connections" from the context menu.

See http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/bridge-network-connections-in-windows-7/

Comment: This does not work at all. I get a bridge, I fixed the metrics to that the wifi has lower number, but the TV does not connect at all.

Comment: Specifically what does not work? Do you detect a connection between the HTPC and the TV? Can you see detect the TV from the wireless AP?